# Is there any method to join/concatenate all DataFrame created?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a range of datetime generate as below and i want to store the datetime as a list in a cell.

example as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date1': ['2020-11-17 13:35:18', '2020-11-17 00:00:45','2020-11-17 00:18:18','2020-11-17 22:45:19'],
                   'date2': ['2020-11-17 13:36:50', '2020-11-17 00:01:53', '2020-11-17 00:19:27','2020-11-17 22:46:40']})

print(df)

OUTPUT:
                 date1                date2
0  2020-11-17 13:35:18  2020-11-17 13:36:50
1  2020-11-17 00:00:45  2020-11-17 00:01:53
2  2020-11-17 00:18:18  2020-11-17 00:19:27
3  2020-11-17 22:45:19  2020-11-17 22:46:40
```

i created the list of datetime range and i would like to add as the third column, but i stuck concatenating the list into a new dataframe

result i get:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    listrange =pd.date_range(start=df['date1'][i], end=df['date2'][i], freq='S')
    a = listrange.append([listrange])
    dd=pd.DataFrame([[a]])
    print(dd)
    aa = pd.concat([df,dd[0]], axis=1, sort=False)
    print(aa)

OUTPUT:
                                                   0
0  DatetimeIndex(['2020-11-17 13:35:18', '2020-11...
                                                   0
0  DatetimeIndex(['2020-11-17 00:00:45', '2020-11...
                                                   0
0  DatetimeIndex(['2020-11-17 00:18:18', '2020-11...
                                                   0
0  DatetimeIndex(['2020-11-17 22:45:19', '2020-11...



                 date1  ...                                                  0
0  2020-11-17 13:35:18  ...  DatetimeIndex(['2020-11-17 13:35:18', '2020-11...
1  2020-11-17 00:00:45  ...                                                NaN
2  2020-11-17 00:18:18  ...                                                NaN
3  2020-11-17 22:45:19  ...                                                NaN

[4 rows x 3 columns]
                 date1  ...                                                  0
0  2020-11-17 13:35:18  ...  DatetimeIndex(['2020-11-17 00:00:45', '2020-11...
1  2020-11-17 00:00:45  ...                                                NaN
2  2020-11-17 00:18:18  ...                                                NaN
3  2020-11-17 22:45:19  ...                                                NaN

[4 rows x 3 columns]
                 date1  ...                                                  0
0  2020-11-17 13:35:18  ...  DatetimeIndex(['2020-11-17 00:18:18', '2020-11...
1  2020-11-17 00:00:45  ...                                                NaN
2  2020-11-17 00:18:18  ...                                                NaN
3  2020-11-17 22:45:19  ...                                                NaN

[4 rows x 3 columns]
                 date1  ...                                                  0
0  2020-11-17 13:35:18  ...  DatetimeIndex(['2020-11-17 22:45:19', '2020-11...
1  2020-11-17 00:00:45  ...                                                NaN
2  2020-11-17 00:18:18  ...                                                NaN
3  2020-11-17 22:45:19  ...                                                NaN

[4 rows x 3 columns]
```

**EXPECTED RESULT:**

```
                                             0
0  DatetimeIndex(['2020-11-17 13:35:18', '2020-11...
1  DatetimeIndex(['2020-11-17 00:00:45', '2020-11...
2  DatetimeIndex(['2020-11-17 00:18:18', '2020-11...
3  DatetimeIndex(['2020-11-17 22:45:19', '2020-11...
```

**then END of RESULT:**

```
                 date1                date2                 **range**
0  2020-11-17 13:35:18  2020-11-17 13:36:50      ['2020-11-17 13:35:18', '2020-11...,'2020-11-17 13:36:50']
1  2020-11-17 00:00:45  2020-11-17 00:01:53      ['2020-11-17 00:00:45', '2020-11...,'2020-11-17 00:01:53'] 
2  2020-11-17 00:18:18  2020-11-17 00:19:27      ['2020-11-17 00:18:18', '2020-11...,'2020-11-17 00:19:27']
3  2020-11-17 22:45:19  2020-11-17 22:46:40      ['2020-11-17 22:45:19', '2020-11...,'2020-11-17 22:46:40']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concat after making all data range.

```
listrange = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    daterange = pd.date_range(start=df['date1'][i], end=df['date2'][i], freq='S')
    listrange.append([daterange])

rangecol = pd.DataFrame(listrange)
print(rangecol)
res = pd.concat([df, rangecol], axis=1, sort=False)
print(res)
```